# How do I find a list of all my StackExchange activity beyond the 5th page?

Tags: feature-request

https://stackexchange.com/users/273436/inquilinekea?tab=activity gives me a list of all of my activity up to the 5th page.

One sample URL is here: https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/273436/?page=5&filter=all

But if I change the "5" to a "10", it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I wonder what the limitation is in place for?  Is it a particularly expensive DB fetch?

Answer (score 2):

You can go further back on the individual sites.  Don't know if the API can be used to gather this easily.